# Orange correspondence analysis widget

Tags: widget, analysis, orange, correspondence

Can anyone tell me how to use the Orange correspondence analysis widget?

I have a table of 11 columns of data with a first column of row names. I have tried to select the data using select attributes widget and connecting to the correspondence analysis widget. But, I did not get any result. Do I have to connect to another widget before the correspondence analysis widget?

Okay, I don't know what code I'm using. I don't know how to access code I was just using the visual interface, which I thought should do the job.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you include the sample code you've tried so far, and tag the language you're using?  Also, please limit your post to a single question :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. The input data for the correspondence analysis need to have discrete variables.
   If you have continuous variables consider PCA instead.
2. For a simple example use of CA, load the [smokers_ct.tab](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/biolab/orange3/master/Orange/datasets/smokers_ct.tab) dataset and use it in CA widget.

Comment: I understood CA works with counts or presence and absence data.

Comment: Yes, CA works on a 2d contingency table. But in Orange Canvas you cannot directly input a contingency table in to the widget. The widget itself will (depending on the user selection) tabulate the occurrences of values for 2 (or more in case of MCA) columns.